# Linq Joining two tables in a VM with GroupBy & OrderByDescending

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, join

I have a two tables in EF 6.1, I need help in joining them to fill an `OverDueEquipVM` , also when I return it, the groupBy throws off the return list saying its not IEnumerable type.

---

`Table 1:` `LaptopsTable` *contains* `Employee Id` & `ManagerId` & `DatesCheckedOut`  `EqipType`

`Table 1:` `EmployeeTable` *contains* `Employee Id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Position` Employee/Mgr.

---

I can query the `Table 1:` for all Items *Overdue* (over a week) , however my results have `EmpID` & `MgrID` and *returning a grouped employee list to the view* set throws an error that its *not IEnumrable* , **how do I join this so that I can display the First + Last names as well? and group it by the emp names in descending order of overduedate** i.e. in VM add the first, last names as well.

```
db.LaptopsTable.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == userId) // loggedin user
           .Where(x => x.date >= checkOutDate.Date  // check overdue?
                                 && x.date < todaysDate.Date)
           .OrderByDescending(x => checkOutDate.Date)
           .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
           .TheOrderBy(x => x.EqipType).ToList();
```

---

```
public class OverDueEquipVM
{
   public int EmployeeId;
   public int ManagerId;

   public string EmployeeName; // First + last
   public string ManagerName;

   public date CheckOutDate;
   public string EqiupType;  // phone laptop etc
   public int EmployeeId;
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error ? please maintain...

Comment: why not use the .Join method with following projection? What you ask for is not anything usually done in Joins, so you'll have to do it in memory.

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM if I change things around I either get a datetime error from linq, or I get an error when returning this as a list, since it does not have IEnumerable, if I use groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you mention is easy: what is the return value of GroupBy and what is the input value for ThenBy?

There is nothing specified (and thus not guaranteed) about the order of the output in GroupBy, so I think it is useless to order anything before grouping. You should OrderBy and ThenBy after the grouping process.

About your OverDueEquipVM.

It seems that you want the list from all `Laptops` from the `Employee` with a given `userId` that are overdue. Apart from some `Laptop` information, you also want the `FirstName` and the `LastName` of the `Employee` who owns this 
`Laptop` as well as hist `ManagerId`.

Because of your GroupBy statement, it seems that there is a one-to-many relation between `Employee` and `Laptop`: every `Employee` has zero or more `Laptops`, and every `Laptop` belongs to exactly one `Employee` using EmployeeId`.

I think there is also a one-to-many relation between `Manager` and `Laptop`: every `Manager` manages zero or more `Laptops`, and every `Laptop` is managed by exactly one `Manager` using foreing key `ManagerId`

Because of your phrase: "Employee/Mgr" I'm not sure whether every Employee has a Manager. I'll assume you want the Manager of the Laptop in your end result.

If you'd configure your Employee / Laptop / Manager classes according to the [Entity Framework One-To-Many conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) you would have had something like:

```
class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // primary key

    // every Employee has zero or more Laptops:
    public virtual ICollection<Laptop> Laptops {get; set;}

    // other properties:
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Manager
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // primary key

    // every Manager manages zero or more Laptops:
    public virtual ICollection<Laptop> Laptops {get; set;}

    // other properties:
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Laptop
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // primary key

    // every Laptop is owned by exactly one Employee using foreign key:
    public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
    public Employee Employee {get; set;}

    // every Laptop is managed by exactly one Manager using foreign key:
    public int ManagerId {get; set;}
    public Manager Manager {get; set;}

    // other properties:
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string  EquipmentType {get; set;}
}
```

Now, given a userId, a checkoutDate and a todaysDate, you want all Laptops owned by this user with a Date between checkOutDate and todaysDate. With every laptop you want the first and last name of the owner of this laptop as well ass the first and last name of the Manger of this laptop.

There are several problems:

You don't want to use the DateTime value of checkoutDate and todaysDate, but their Date property. Normally you'd use DateTime.Date for this. However Ling does not support this function in IQueryable.

The easiest method is to extract the date before you use it in your linq statement:

```
checkoutDate = checkoutDate.Date;
todaysDate = todaysDate.Date;
// TODO: create a LINQ query
```

Another method would be to use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D))

Another problem is that you want to concatenate the FristName and LastName of Employee and Manager. String.Concat is not supported by Entity Framework. The best would be to remember the FirstName and LastName in your OverDueEquipm, and add a FullName property:

```
class Name
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string FullName
    {
        get {return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName;}
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public Name Name {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Manager
{
    public Name Name {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

The nice thing is that if you want to change the idea of a Name, for instance add a middle name, or want to use Initials, or other changes, you don't have to change your Employee nor Manager.

If you really don't want to introduce a Name class, you'll have to do the concatenation AsEnumerable.

Having done this, your query will be easy:

```
var result = myDbContext.Laptops
    .Where(lapto => laptop.EmployeeId == userId
    && checkoutDate <= laptop.Date 
    && laptop.Date <= todaysDate)
    .Select(laptop => new OverdueEquipVm
    {
        EmployeeId = laptop.EmployeeId,
        MangerId = laptop.MangerId,
        Date = laptop.CheckoutDate,
        EquipmentType = laptop.EquipmentType,

        EmployeeName = new Name
        {
            FirstName = laptop.Employee.FirstName,
            LastName = laptop.Employee.LastName,
        },
        ManagerName  = new Name
        {
            FirstName = laptop.Manager.FirstName,
            LastName = laptop.Manager.LastName,
        },
    });
```

Comment: very nice, you were on the money about the linq date issue, I see the way you created emplyee name & manager name... trying it now... will mark as answer if it worksout. Since `I also have to persist this back to DB` I have is when I am converting it VM lists and back, can you please share an `implicit static` function helper/explanation ; or how would i persist this back to the db?

Comment: Do not understand: "have to persist this back to DB I have is when I am converting it VM lists and back". Do you mean you have to put the result of the query back in the database? Why? The information is already in the database, you just queried it!.

Comment: For me the user is making updates, to updates to this when he views it, for e.g. change the checkout date - I want to be able to save that. In this case its over way right? how can I make the mapping such that it works both ways - that is save this from the VM back to model. I thought implicit does it. I marked as answer BTW :)

Comment: -- Also does the query go in the `VM object`, can I include the DB context there, if I am reusing this everywhere.  My current implementation has this in my repository object